# "Affected neighboring topics" sounds wrong

Tags: word-choice

I found in our documentation the phrase **affected neighboring topic**. It looks unfamiliar to me. Is *affected related topics* a better way to introduce a list of issues, which are influenced by this topic?

Comment: What is the general context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds reasonable to me, although it isn't a well-known phrase, and the wider context would need to show how topics can be "neighbouring".

"Neighbouring" is different from "related" in that it normally means things which are immediately next to each other, whereas things can be more 'distantly related'.

Are these topics "neighbouring" in that they are neighbouring chapters in a book? Or is there some other structure of learning that would mean moving from one to another? If not, then "related" may be better.